# Setting to brush texture follow the path of drawing?

Tags: sculpting, texture-painting

iam currently using sculpt brush of a animal fur, but iam not happy with how it works. All the settings make it like the stencil that the texture is in one direction and it doesn't look natural. Is there a setting that tilt the pattern as Iam dragging the mouse so the pattern is created naturally with the movement and it will tilt when the brush change direction.

(P.S. I would like to have the same effect as well for texture painting, if there is the same setting)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the option you want.
Properties panel(<kbd>N</kbd>)>Tool>Texture
[image: rake]

From manual:

> Rake R
>
> Angle follows the direction of the brush stroke. Not available with 3D textures. (Shortcut sculpting only.)

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/sculpt_paint/brush/texture.html

Comment: Oh where is that in 2.8 I cant find it

Comment: @Fowl it is right under the place where you specify your brush texture

Comment: Finally found it, I didnt realized that I used 3D texture

Comment: @convector wait, so it does not work in sculpting at all?

Comment: @Fowl it does work with 2d texture but not 3d textures.

Comment: @convector when I create a texture and use it in paint there is the rake option but as soon as I use the same texture for a sculpt brush, the rake option is missing

Comment: @Fowl what did you set the mapping to? Only setting it to view plane, area plane and random will have the rake option.

Comment: @convector thanks, that was the problem